# .NET REST API for eBay (Product APIs)

Tags: c#, .net, rest, api, sdk

I  am looking to develop a desktop application (in either c# or VB.NET) that will allow the user to enter some product information and provide them with a button that will upload that product onto their eBay account.

I am familiar with REST and have developed many other applications that communicate with a REST API for other platforms, however, after days and days of searching for the documentation for an eBay API that will allow me to do this, I've had no luck.

The closest I've gotten is finding a big list of different APIs that eBay offer: https://developer.ebay.com/docs

If anyone could provide me with an answer to whether it is even possible to make these sorts of requests (using REST) and some links for their documentation, that would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the functionality that the API needs to have:

1. Create a product on the user's eBay account.
2. Update a product's inventory.
3. Completely update a product.
4. Retrieve any orders that have been placed containing the products that were purchased.
5. Fulfill an order.

If it is not even possible to make these requests (using REST as I do believe there may be something out there using SOAP), could someone please provide me with a link to an SDK in either C# or VB.NET, that will make these requests in some other way.

Comment: https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/static/inventory/managing-inventory-and-offers.html

Comment: @Saravanan I thought that it might be this one, however, I can't seem to find any endpoints to with creating a product. Am I just being blind?